# Is it possible to change order of inline elements without changing HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have two inline elements and I want to change the order of these elements without changing the HTML code. It's possible to do this with CSS only? I know how to change order with flex and grid etc. but these are only for block elements and I am curious if this can be done with inline elements also

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
h1 {
}
h1:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
  </h1>
  <!-- I need this without changing html -->
  <h1>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: is the text always the same for the red part? If the width is fixed there are some CSS only solution

Comment: Both text are dynamic

Comment: How specific is the new order? If it's simply reversed then I believe it should be possible, however if you want to select positions for each item, you may have to resort to flex layout.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can post the solution with fixed width also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the width is fixed you can rely on `text-indent` and `position:absolute`

```css
h1 {
  position:relative;
  text-indent:122px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-indent:0;
}
span {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
*, *::after, *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically this does make the red `span` have `display: block`, but it's probably the closest approach you can get.

Comment: @DBS that's why I asked if the width of the text is always the same or not and I considered the fact that a small text will not wrap since it's small after all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with CSS only you can fiddle about with pseudo elements and get the required effect - but it's a bit hacky because it requires whoever is changing the short string to also change it in the CSS (e.g. with a CSS variable).

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.red {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;
  /* to account for box sizing and border */
  z-index: 1;
  /* incase this is e.g. clickable */
  border: none;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

span:nth-child(1)::before,
span:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: 'EKP itd.';
}

span:nth-child(1)::before,
span:nth-child(1)::after {
  color: red;
}

span:nth-child(1)::after {
  color: transparent;
  padding: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue 0 2px, transparent 2px 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

If not by CSS, then you can do it with JavaScript

```js
const container = document.querySelector("div h1");
container.append(container.querySelector("span"))
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
h1 {
}
h1:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
span {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
  </h1>
  <!-- I need this without changing html -->
  <h1>
    <span class='red'>EKP itd.</span>
    <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```